# Show warning when using implicit type in typescript

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-eslint, typescript-types, implicit-typing

I'd like to make vscode to show warning when I do not annotate type even if typescript infer type correctly (I'm not talking of noImplicitAny option).

Is there an option in tsconfig that could allow me to have this behavior ?

Comment: "I'm not really comfortable to ask question about using vscode in stackoverflow" questions about using text editors for programming are on-topic here. This however isn't a great question: can you add some example code and pictures that show the issue? Also the tsconfig setting you are looking for is [noImplicitAny](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny)

Comment: @jcalz ts is not about making the code more strict ? If I let the compiler infer the type when using an external module, What happen If I decide to update the module and for some reasons the type I did not annotate change on the module ?

Comment: @JaredSmith its not noImplicitAny, I want to show warning when the compiler infer type for any type not "any" type (confusing here).

Comment: @jcalz edited, I do not really know if I should add code to it since its pretty short but simple at the same time.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't provide such functionality. If you want to require type annotations you could use a linter like ESLint and its [`typedef` rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/typedef/). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write an answer; otherwise, what is missing?

Comment: @jcalz, yes, reading the doc, it seem to suit my needs

Comment: I will write an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: I also just found vscode config   "typescript.inlayHints.{variable,parameter,functionLikeReturn}Types.enabled" . who doesn't not show warning but show the infer type, which is not that bad but its not a direct answer to the question. I'll leave that here in case that could be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript itself doesn't have a setting that will warn you if you don't [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) a variable whose type can be inferred.  The only time such things are considered a problem in the language is if the inference fails and the type implicitly falls back to [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).

For functionality like this, you might want to use a linter like [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) with a rule like [`@typescript-eslint/typedef`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/typedef/), whose description reads

> This rule can enforce type annotations in locations regardless of whether they're required. This is typically used to maintain consistency for element types that sometimes require them.

Note: this is not necessarily *recommended*: the official TS handbook about annotations implies that you should normally just rely on the inferred types, and even the ESLint rule linked above says :

> ⚠ CAUTION
>
> Requiring type annotations unnecessarily can be cumbersome to maintain and generally reduces code readability. TypeScript is often better at inferring types than easily written type annotations would allow.
>
> **Instead of enabling `typedef`, it is generally recommended to use the `--noImplicitAny` and `--strictPropertyInitialization` compiler options to enforce type annotations only when useful.**

Comment: All true, but I think it's worth noting that this is a poor way to learn the language. No one is realistically going to think of, let alone fully elaborate, the complex inferred types involving intersections and unions. Some of the most useful functionality comes from CFA and unreachable code analysis. It catches real bugs. Again, it's not a flaw in this answer but I would strongly recommend against such a practice especially within function bodies.

Comment: @AluanHaddad for what it's worth, after asking my question I read some articles and indeed I understand better why it's not a good idea, I left my question and mark the answer because it still can be useful but I'm not using it, I instead set the vscode variable I talked about in the comments section of the question. That allow me to see the infer type and help me understand better I think

Comment: Updated the answer so as not to imply that this is *recommended*